# Weak convergence of random variables: class of test functions

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X, X_n$ $(n \geq 1)$ be real-valued random variables. We say that $X_n$ converges in distribution / weakly to $X$ and we write $X_n \overset{d}\to X$ whenever
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)] \quad \text{for all } f \in \color{red}{C_b(\mathbb{R})}.$$
I am wondering under what conditions it is sufficient to consider a smaller class of functions, e.g. bounded and Lipschitz and still get convergence in distribution.

I think that convergence for bounded Lipschitz functions always implies converence of the above quantity for $C_c(\mathbb{R})$-functions. But to get to $C_b(\mathbb{R})$-functions, we need some assumptions on $X_n$ and $X$. I think that $X_n$ and $X$ uniformly bounded works and that $\max(|X|, | X_1 |, |X_2|, \dots) \leq Y$ for some $L_1$-random variable should also work.

**Question:** Are there other good criterions for $X_n, X$ that imply $X_n \overset{d}\to X$ whenever

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)] \quad \text{for all } f \in \{\color{red}{\text{bounded and Lipschitz}}\}.$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weak convergence: equivalence of definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789282/weak-convergence-equivalence-of-definitions)

Comment: From convergence for $C_{c}(\Bbb{R})$ functions to $C_{b}$ is not difficult provided $X$ is indeed a "random variable" , $X$ is a measurable function from a probability space and not just any finite measure space. If limiting distribution is a probability distribution, then convergence for $C_{c}$ implies convergence for $C_{b}$. But perhaps, the most important small "class" of functions that you need is $E(e^{itX})$, i.e. characteristic functions.

Comment: For the jump $C_{c}$ to $C_{b}$, what you can do is first prove that $E(\mathbf{1}_{X_{n}\in(a,b]})\to E(\mathbf{1}_{X\in(a,b]})$ for all $a,b$ such that the distribution of $X$ is continuous at those points by approximating the indicator compactly supported functions. (i.e. just 1 in the interval and then linearly interpolating to $0$). Then you can show that $P(X_{n}\in (a,b])\to P(X\in (a,b])$ for all $a,b$ as above implies convergence of the cdfs at continuity points. More details can be found in Sidney Resnick A Probability Path.